# ASP.NET MVC Kendo TreeView with signalR

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

Anybody know how to work with Kendo TreeView and SignalR?
Because I have this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("vehicleList")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.SignalR()
        .AutoSync(true)
        .Transport(tr => tr.Promise("hubStart")
            .Hub("hub")
            .Client(c => c.Read("read2"))
            .Server(s => s.Read("read2"))
        )
        .Schema(s => s.Model(m => {
            m.Id("id");
            m.Field("Name", typeof(string));
            m.Children("Children");
            m.HasChildren("HasChildren");
        }))
    )
)
```

But when try expand or select item I have error that treeview require `server.create` method. But I try only expand or select tree

My hub looks like:

```
var vehicle = allVehicle.Where(d => d.ParentId == null || d.ParentId == Guid.Empty)
    .Select(v => new VehicleTree() {
        Name = v.Name,
        Id = v.Id,
        hasChildren = false
    }).ToList();
var groups = allVehicle.Where(d => d.ParentId != Guid.Empty).Select(g => new VehicleTree() {
    Id = g.ParentId,
    Name = g.GroupName,
    hasChildren = true
}).Distinct().ToList();

foreach(var g in groups) {
    g.Children = allVehicle.Where(v => v.ParentId == g.Id).Select(v => new VehicleTree() {
        Name = v.Name,
        Id = v.Id,
        hasChildren = false
    }).ToList();
}

var result = new List<VehicleTree>();
result.AddRange(groups);
result.AddRange(vehicle);
return result;
```